# Bottom align collapsed div inside another div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, position

I'm trying to create a little chat client to plug into my website, and am having trouble aligning a collapsed `div` to the bottom of it's container `div`.

I have a `div` with two chat windows (also `div`s) in it - by default both windows are maximized.

When I minimize one of the windows, the panel collapses upwards, at the top of the container `div`.

When both are minimized, it works as desired, with both minimized bars at the bottom of the page.

I'd paste images, but I'm new to stackoverflow and can't post images.

How can I force the collapsed div to the bottom of the container, when another div inside it is not minimized?

It can be seen in action here :

[ChatTest](http://test.dode.com.au/chattest.aspx)

And here's the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>
    <script src="Scripts/chat.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <style>     

        .panel-resizable {
            resize: both;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .chat-container {
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: fixed;
            /*height: 500px;*/
            max-height: 500px;
            /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
        }

        .chatblah {
            bottom: 0;
            /*position: fixed;*/
            float: right;
            margin-left: 0;
            right: 0;
            /*border: 1px solid green;*/
        }

        .chat-window {
            bottom: 0;
            float: right;
            margin-left: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            max-width: 280px;
            max-height: 500px;
            min-width: 280px;
            /*border: 1px solid red;*/
        }

            .chat-window > div > .panel {
                border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
            }

        .icon_minim {
            padding: 2px 10px;
        }

        .top-bar {
            background: #666;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="chat-container">
            <div class="chatblah">
                <div class="panel panel-warning table-responsive chat-window">
                    <div class="panel-heading top-bar">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_1">Fred</a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="text-align: right;">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_1"><span id="minim_chat_window" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus icon_minim"></span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon_close" data-id="chat_window_1"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse_1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-resizable">
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtChatID_1" value="1" />
                            <table style="width: 260px;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <!--Chat Message element-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 26px; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid white">
                                            <img src="Images/defaultuser.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="background-color: #EDF5FC; border: 1px solid white">This is a test message that will go over a couple of lines.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-right" colspan="2">
                                            <h5><small>You • 12:07am 19 Dec 2017</small></h5>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!--End Chat Message element-->


                                    <!--Chat Message element-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 26px; vertical-align: top">
                                            <img src="Images/defaultuser.png" style="border: 1px solid white; width: 24px; height: 24px" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="background-color: #F2F2F2; border: 1px solid white">This is a response to that message</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-right" colspan="2">
                                            <h5><small>Joan • 12:09am 19 Dec 2017</small></h5>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!--End Chat Message element-->




                                    <!--Message Input-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <textarea class="form-control chatInput" rows="3" id="txtMessage_1" placeholder="Type a message....."></textarea>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!--End Message Input-->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="chatblah">
                <div class="panel panel-warning table-responsive chat-window">
                    <div class="panel-heading top-bar">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_2">Joan</a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="text-align: right;">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_2"><span id="minim_chat_window2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus icon_minim"></span></a>
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon_close" data-id="chat_window_1"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse_2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-resizable">
                            <input type="hidden" id="txtChatID_2" value="1" />
                            <table style="width: 260px;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <!--Chat Message element-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 26px; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid white">
                                            <img src="Images/defaultuser.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="background-color: #EDF5FC; border: 1px solid white">This is a test message that will go over a couple of lines.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-right" colspan="2">
                                            <h5><small>Fred • 12:07am 19 Dec 2017</small></h5>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!--End Chat Message element-->


                                    <!--Chat Message element-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 26px; vertical-align: top">
                                            <img src="Images/defaultuser.png" style="border: 1px solid white; width: 24px; height: 24px" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="background-color: #F2F2F2; border: 1px solid white">This is a response to that message</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-right" colspan="2">
                                            <h5><small>You • 12:09am 19 Dec 2017</small></h5>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!--End Chat Message element-->




                                    <!--Message Input-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <textarea class="form-control chatInput" rows="3" id="txtMessage_2" placeholder="Type a message....."></textarea>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!--End Message Input-->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any and all suggestions most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox and use `flex-direction: column;` and `justify-content: flex-end;` to align your chat elements to bottom.

```
.chat-container {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    /* height: 500px; */
    max-height: 500px;
    /* border: 1px solid blue; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.chatblah {
   flex: 1;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class **fix** to second .chatblah div and then use this css

```
.chatblah.fix {
    position: absolute;
    right: 290px;
}
```

Here is the screenshot http://prntscr.com/hpz073

Comment: Hi Taimur,

Thanks for your reply, but this I can't get your solution to display as I need - it stacks the windows on top of each other, 290px from the right hand margin.